# malloc allocation error - llvm ir code

Tags: malloc, llvm, llvm-ir

In the below code, I create several arrays that are 4 elements long. This works fine however, when I make them larger (5 or 6) elements I get the below error.

#### IR Code

```
declare [4 x double] @malloc(double)

declare double @printd(double)

define double @__anon_expr0() {
entry:
  %foo = alloca [4 x double]
  %calltmp = call [4 x double] @malloc(double 2.560000e+02)
  %0 = insertvalue [4 x double] %calltmp, double 1.000000e+00, 0
  %1 = insertvalue [4 x double] %0, double 1.000000e+00, 1
  %2 = insertvalue [4 x double] %1, double 1.000000e+00, 2
  store [4 x double] %2, [4 x double]* %foo
  %3 = getelementptr [4 x double], [4 x double]* %foo, i32 0, i32 0
  %__ = load double, double* %3
  %calltmp1 = call double @printd(double %__)
  %4 = getelementptr [4 x double], [4 x double]* %foo, i32 0, i32 0
  %__2 = load double, double* %4
  %calltmp3 = call double @printd(double %__2)
  ret double %calltmp3
}

define i32 @main() {
  call double @__anon_expr0 ()
  ret i32 0
}
```

#### Error

```
built(16968,0x7fff8f39c380) malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=140732867354624) failed (error code=3)
*** error: can't allocate region
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

What is causing the error? I would think that malloc could handle more than a 4 element array. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `malloc` is `void* malloc(size_t size)` where `size_t` is a platform-specific integer type (32-bit on 32-bit platforms, 64-bit on 64-bit platforms).

So when you declare it as taking a double and call it as such, you're invoking undefined behaviour. In practice what will happen is that you're moving the value 256.0 into the double register for first arguments and then calling `malloc`, which will read its argument from the integer register for first arguments (which was never initialized).

Instead you should declare `malloc` to take an `i64` on 64-platforms and `i32` on 32-bit. And then you should also call it with an integer argument (i.e. `256` instead of `2.56e2`).

Another problem is the return type: `malloc` returns a pointer, not an array (C function never return arrays - that isn't even syntactically possible). So it should be declared and used as such.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!